# Are references helpful when operating in a constexpr/compile-time context only?

Tags: c++, reference, constexpr

I am exploring the world of [`constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) and have decided to create a class that should only be used in constexpr context and other compile-time constructs.

Usually, I take great care to provide all necessary overloads a class may need, for example:

```
template <typename T>
struct Thing
{
    Thing(T value) : m_value(value) {}

    T &value() & { return m_value; }
    const T &value() const & { return m_value; }

    T &&value() && { return std::move(m_value); }

private:
    T m_value;
};
```

The set of overloads for `Thing::value` should take care of efficient access to the stored value, no unnecessary copies are made. If the `Thing` instance is a temporary, the stored value can even be moved out.

But what if `Thing` is only to be used as a constexpr type, are all these different overloads for `Thing::value` required or even helpful at all? Or would the following be equivalent:

```
template <typename T>
struct Thing
{
    constexpr Thing(T value) : m_value(value) {}

    constexpr T value() const;

private:
    T m_value;
};
```

---

**My question basically boils down to:** are references helpful (more efficient) when operating in a constexpr/compile-time context only; or is passing everything by value equivalent?

Comment: Do references even make sense at compile time? A reference is a handle to an object in memory, but given it's only evaluated at compile time, then I would have thought it makes no difference

Comment: [References actually makes sense at compile-time](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1676d70db7cd413). At least and as an example, the standard allows you to use them as template arguments with some limitations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question basically boils down to: are references helpful (more efficient) when operating in a constexpr/compile-time context only; or is passing everything by value equivalent?

It's a matter of what's your actual problem and how you plan to solve it. In most of the cases (all of them?) you won't need to use references in such a context, I agree, but you can still use them if required.

Here as a minimal, working example:

```
const int i = 0;

template <typename T>
struct Thing {
    constexpr Thing(const T &value) : m_value(value) {}
    constexpr const T & value() const { return m_value; }

private:
    const T & m_value;
};

int main() {
    static_assert(Thing<int>{i}.value() == 0, "!");
}
```

See it up and running on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/H2LTB3jGaDubBXRz).

So, *are references helpful (more efficient)* in this case? Well, it's not a matter of efficiency or whatever. To use references in such a context you have to have a good reason and the language sets a lot of limitations. They solve a specific problem, it's not your taste to decide to use references.
If your problem requires you to use references, they are there for you (and please, contact me - I'm just curious to know what's that problem!). Otherwise feel free to keep on with passing by value.

Comment: I see that using references at compile-time might be a requirement to solve certain problems. My problem does not require them (luckily). I specifically mentioned *efficiency* in my question because somehow I thought that using references instead of values might lead to shorter compile times?

Comment: @MaartenBamelis I don't think you'll notice differences in either cases.